# How to change the title of "question" environment from English to another language?

Tags: exsheets

I want to change the title question in English to other language. How to do that? You can choose any other language in your answer.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{exsheets}

\begin{document}
\begin{question}
What is your name?
\end{question}
\end{document}
```

Bonus question: I still don't understand why the default language (English) uses "Exercise" rather than "Question" for the question title? Intuitively, `question` environment should be titled "Question", `solution` environment should be titled `Solution`. What do you think?

Comment: Ah, no. I found the answer. It depends on the `type` key. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Answer updated with an answer for the bonus question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Load `babel` and use the desired localization (whether as a global option for the class or as local option for `babel` (in this case load `exsheets` *after* `babel`)):

```
\documentclass[spanish]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{exsheets}

\begin{document}
\begin{question}
¿Cómo te llamas?
\end{question}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In a multi-lingual document you can use, for example. `\selectlanguage, (after registering the languages to`babel`) or the environment`otherlanguage` for switching languages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman,english,spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{exsheets}

\begin{document}
\begin{question}
¿Cómo te llamas?
\end{question}

\selectlanguage{ngerman}
\begin{question}
Wie heissen Sie?
\end{question}

\selectlanguage{english}
\begin{question}
What is your name?
\end{question}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to change the string used in the localization, you can use

```
\DeclareTranslation{<Language>}{exsheets-exercise-name}{<New string>}
```

For example, when using the spanish modulo for babel, to change the default "Ejercicio" to "Cuestión", one would use

```
\DeclareTranslation{Spanish}{exsheets-exercise-name}{Cuestión}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{exsheets}

\DeclareTranslation{Spanish}{exsheets-exercise-name}{Cuestión}

\begin{document}
\begin{question}
¿Cómo te llamas?
\end{question}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A similar procedure can be applied with `polyglossia` (in case of XeLaTeX).

The documentation also gives advise on how to proceed if the desired localization is not available and offers an example for Danish:

```
\DeclareTranslation{Danish}{exsheets-exercise-name}
{\O{}velse}
\DeclareTranslation{Danish}{exsheets-question-name}
{Opgave}
\DeclareTranslation{Danish}{exsheets-solution-name}
{Opl\o{}sning}
```

To answer the bonus question, the `question` environment has an associated `type` which determines the string used in the title; in English, the default type is `exercise`, which causes the `question` environment to be titled "Exercise"; if you want the title to be "Question", you have to use the `exam` type:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{exsheets}


\begin{document}
\begin{question}
What is your name?
\end{question}

\begin{question}[type=exam]
What is your name?
\end{question}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @PSTikZ the author recommends, for these cases, the option I mentioned at the end using `\DeclareTranslation`.

Comment: I couldn't have given a better answer... :)

Comment: BTW there's always the last resort to set `\begin{question}[name=Whatever]` or `\SetupExSheets{question/name=Whatever}`.

Comment: For greek it's the same methode?

Comment: @giannis Sure! But it depends on your settings for the Greek language. Something like `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}
\usepackage{exsheets}

\DeclareTranslation{Greek}{exsheets-exercise-name}{φύσις}

\begin{document}

\begin{question}
\end{question}

\end{document}` (soory, but I don't know the Greek word for "Exercise") should work. If this is not waht you want, please feel free to open a follow-up question.